# How to run a SQL command when an email is recieved

Tags: php, sql, email

I have a site, which I made myself.
It runs on a database and displays the content out of three rows: date, content and title.

I want to run a script (preferably PHP) that reads the email, and gets the date sent, the content, and the subject of the email and inserts it to the database.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Your mail is send by your server not php. So you can't say mail is  received or not. Even using php you can't say mail reach at destination too...

Comment: How could I do it then?

Comment: There is now way using php.

Comment: Could I do it using Perl?

Comment: Sorry I don't know perl...

Comment: There is a way using PHP, but I'm only aware of it through Wordpress. That isn't to say there isn't a way without Wordpress. 

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email

Using this function, you send an email to a secret address and Wordpress creates a post (and writes to your DB to do so). 

You can reverse engineer their class and use it to check for mails received then use PHP to write to the database.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.imap.php Could I use that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own mail server and use it to store incoming mail to MySQL database. See this: https://library.linode.com/email/postfix/postfix2.9.6-dovecot2.0.19-mysql

Other option is to make timed shell script (crontab) execute php and read/store mail for database.

Comment: How could I make the crontab? I use cPanel and WHM.

Comment: I think cPanel has crontab option too: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs Otherwise you need SSH account to server. There is also option to create "fakecron" which runs code with certain interval.

Comment: Anything you need :) Not going to create such of code for you here.. not right place for that..

Comment: I don't get how I would check the all the emails for update@thomasdoyle.me.uk. :|

Comment: If you don't know.. google.. and learn.. really simple. I didn't know everything when i was born :) I think "php read email imap" will give you thousands of results..